# Sending simultaneous requests using threading

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading

I have been trying to improve my Discord sending webhooks functions where I have multiple dictionaries, as you will see in the code below:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import time
from threading import Thread
from discord_webhook import DiscordEmbed, DiscordWebhook

DISCORD_POSITIVE = {
    "hello": {
        "US": "https://discordapp.com/api/webhooks/53235795325234093583/fwewefwefewfw",
        "EU": "https://discordapp.com/api/webhooks/53235723523554285313/eafkuhafkjahfkje"
    },

    "world": {
        "US": "https://discordapp.com/api/webhooks/3245252525/dsflgshglksgjdrlskg",
        "EU": "https://discordapp.com/api/webhooks/2352352525253/2AW0ufHvn3werwerliweurlk"
    },

    "test": {
        "US": "https://discordapp.com/api/webhooks/45764747457457/1125151aefaefafa",
        "EU": "https://discordapp.com/api/webhooks/63456346346346/eliaulökeajealkgjealkjgea"
    }
}

DISCORD_NEGATIVE = {
    "hello": {
        "SE": "https://discordapp.com/api/webhooks/5323534634633583/fasdfasasf",
        "EU": "https://discordapp.com/api/webhooks/53235346346354285313/sefseafasfsafe"
    },

    "world": {
        "US": "https://discordapp.com/api/webhooks/3243463464365/ergergegrergearg",
        "EU": "https://discordapp.com/api/webhooks/23567896786725253/awdfawdawda"
    },

    "test": {
        "US": "https://discordapp.com/api/webhooks/474645745457457/ergegrgesrgs",
        "EU": "https://discordapp.com/api/webhooks/634561241242146346/asgasgasrgsd"
    }
}

def main(data):

    """
    data["name"] = Hello
    data["link"] = https://google.com
    data["status"] = Welcome!
    data["image"] = https://p.bigstockphoto.com/GeFvQkBbSLaMdpKXF1Zv_bigstock-Aerial-View-Of-Blue-Lakes-And--227291596.jpg
    data["keyword"] = Will be either True or False, If True = DISCORD_POSITIVE else DISCORD_NEGATIVE
    data['webhook'] = Either hello, world or test
    """
    
    embed = DiscordEmbed(title=data["name"], url=data["link"], description=data["status"], color=10881109)

    embed.set_thumbnail(url=data["image"])
            
    if data['keyword']:
        
        for region, discord_webhooks in DISCORD_POSITIVE[data['webhook']].items():
            webhook = DiscordWebhook(
                url=discord_webhooks,
            )

            webhook.add_embed(embed)

            Thread(
                target=threding_test,
                args=(
                    data,
                    region,
                    webhook
                )
            ).start()

    else:

        for region, discord_webhooks in DISCORD_NEGATIVE[data['webhook']].items():
            
            webhook = DiscordWebhook(
                url=discord_webhooks,
            )

            webhook.add_embed(embed)

            Thread(
                target=threding_test,
                args=(
                    data,
                    region,
                    webhook
                )
            ).start()

    return


def threding_test(data, region, webhook):

        response = webhook.execute()

        if response.ok:
            print(f"Succesfully sent to Discord [{region}]")
            return

        else:
            raise ValueError(
                f"Request to slack returned an error {response.status_code}, the response is \n{response.text}")
```

My biggest goal here was to run the multiple dicts etc:

```
"test": {
    "US": "https://discordapp.com/api/webhooks/474645745457457/ergegrgesrgs",
    "EU": "https://discordapp.com/api/webhooks/634561241242146346/asgasgasrgsd"
}
```

simultaneously so that US sends the requests for itself and EU for itself instead of waiting for each other to do one by one to gain speed improvements. My idea was then to do a for loop through the `DISCORD_POSITIVE/NEGATIVE` and loop through given `data['webhook']` and for each loop -> I will create a thread to send requests and then "kill" the thread after it has been sent. And this is the whole purpose pretty much, to gain fast time requests instead of being dependent on each other :)

Please let me know if there is anything that I might have missed.

Comment: So, does your code work? I.e. does it actually run in parallel? If not, it would be off-topic here.

Comment: @Graipher The code does work :) I do not see any problems when running it either. besides that you need real webhooks from Discord which I cannot provide here since someone can spam my discord. However the code does work! :D